# swr_convert is trying to write to an empty buffer. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: c++, c, audio, ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpe's `swr_convert` to convert `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` audio. I've been successful converting to a different sample format (e.g. `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT` and `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16`), but I'm running into trouble when I'm trying to keep the `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` sample format but change the sample rate.

When converting `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` to `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP`, swr_convert attempts to write to an empty buffer.

I'm using `swr_convert` to convert from 22050 Hz `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP` to 16000 Hz `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP`.

I initialized `SwrContext` like so:

```
 if (swr_alloc_set_opts2(
            &resample_context,
            &pAVContext->ch_layout, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 16000,
            &pAVContext->ch_layout, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 22050, 0, NULL) < 0)
            return ERR_SWR_INIT_FAIL;

        if(swr_init(resample_context) < 0)
            return ERR_SWR_INIT_FAIL;
```

and when I call it like this, the program tries to write to a null buffer and crashes.

```
        samples_decoded = swr_convert(ctx->pSwrContext,
            &pDecodedAudio, numOutSamples,
            (const uint8_t**)&pDecodedFrame->data, pDecodedFrame->nb_samples);
```

So far I've traced the problem to swr_convert_internal

```
if(s->int_sample_fmt == s->out_sample_fmt && s->out.planar
       && !(s->out_sample_fmt==AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S32P && (s->dither.output_sample_bits&31))){
        //Sample format is planar and input format is same as output format
        if(preout==in){
            out_count= FFMIN(out_count, in_count); 
            av_assert0(s->in.planar);
            copy(out, in, out_count);
            return out_count;
        }
        else if(preout==postin) preout= midbuf= postin= out;
        else if(preout==midbuf) preout= midbuf= out;
        else                    preout= out;
    }
```

That if bit of code assigns `out` to `preout`, but `out`'s data is unitialized. Later on FFmpeg tries to write to the uninitialized block.

I've tested this in 5.1 and in the snapshot build, and it crashes both of them.

So, am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something wrong. Packet audio is a contiguous block of memory and can be referenced by one pointer, but planar audio has a different pointer to each channel. To fix this, I got two pointers to my `pDecodedAudio` block.

```
uint8_t* convertedData [2] = {
    pDecodedAudio ,
    pDecodedAudio + (numOutSamples * ctx->output_sample_size)
};
        
samples_decoded = swr_convert(ctx->pSwrContext,
    convertedData, numOutSamples,
    pDecodedFrame->data, pDecodedFrame->nb_samples);
```

See the comments in AVFrame.

```
/*
* For planar audio, each channel has a separate data pointer, and
* linesize[0] contains the size of each channel buffer.
* For packed audio, there is just one data pointer, and linesize[0]
* contains the total size of the buffer for all channels.
*
* Note: Both data and extended_data should always be set in a valid frame,
* but for planar audio with more channels that can fit in data,
* extended_data must be used in order to access all channels.
*/
uint8_t **extended_data;
```